# Copy font style of ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton gives a nice looking button by default. And I would like to copy its font style and size for other UIButton. How can I retrieve the font style and size from a ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton after it is set?

I imagine there is a way similar to something like the below

```
fileprivate let appleButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()
fileprivate let fbButton = UIButton()

// set appleButton constraint etc etc…
// then,

fbButton.titleLabel.font = appleButton. sth sth…
```

[image]

Comment: It's a `UIControl`, and there is no open API for that. You could iterate the subviews, etc and find it or use private API, but it might break change in next iOS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a custom button class with an imageView and lable